# Freeze the output screen for a certain amount of time in c++

Tags: c++

I've been trying to make a snake game in c++. While making the snake move I want the snake to be frozen to its position for 1 second and then print the new position.
I made the following function for that:

```
void wait_time(int wait_t){
        time_t curr=time(NULL);
        time_t nav_t=time(NULL);
        while(1){
            if (nav_t-curr==wait_t) {
                break;
            }
            else{
                nav_t=time(NULL);
            }
        }
}
```

But while this function is being executed my previous output doesn't stay. A part of the output is removed. This my main function that controls all functions:

```
void run_game(){
    initial=time(NULL);
    inital_parameter();
    gotoxy(0,2);
    game_display();
    wait_time(1);
    game_movement();location_disp();
    game_display();
    gotoxy(0,100);
}
```

Comment: As a side note, bear in mind that performing a sleep will mean that if the user presses a key (say esc) you will continue sleeping, and ignore the input until you finally get around to reading it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With C++11 you can use [std::this_thread::sleep_for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for), to pause execution for some amount of time.

The linked page include the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    // using namespace std::chrono_literals; // C++14
    std::cout << "Hello waiter" << std::endl;
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2)); // C++11
    // std::this_thread::sleep_for(2s); // C++14
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> elapsed = end-start;
    std::cout << "Waited " << elapsed.count() << " ms\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use your standard library:

```
std::this_thread::sleep_for(2s);
```

The `2s` is a time literal but you can also do something like

```
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds{2});
```

Comment: beware that chrono literals are c++14, not c++11

Answer (score 1):

**First way**
`chrono` library and `std::this_thread::sleep_for( your-time )`

**Second way**
`unistd.h` that has 2 function
One for waiting in *second*  another for waining in *microsecond*

`sleep( 1 );`
**or**
`usleep( 1000000 );`